Solve and find the non-trivial solutions : $x^2 + xy + xz = 0$, $y^2 + yz + yx = 0$, $z^2 + zx + zy = 0$ .

Solve and find the non-trivial solutions : $x^2 + xy + xz = 0$, $y^2 + yz + yx = 0$, $z^2 + zx + zy = 0$ .

Summing them up, giving $(x + y + z)^2 = 0 \implies x + y + z = 0$
Now substituting any variable negative of sum of other twos not helping so putting.
So putting one of them $0$ giving $a$ and $-a$ values for other two variables for some real $a$ . But this isn't a general way of doing . So how to generally solve it for non trivial solutions ?

Your equations can be also written as
\begin{align}
x(x+y+z)&=0;\\
y(x+y+z)&=0;\\
z(x+y+z)&=0.
\end{align}
Hence any triple $(x,y,z)$ is a solution once $x+y+z=0$, i.e. triples $\{(x,y,-x-y),x,y\in\mathbb{R}\}$.

And if x+y+z ≠ 0, then at least one of x, y, z is not 0, so the three equations cannot all be true .
